# Video's transferred from HFS+ to Ext4 wont play on Ubuntu

Tags: mount, video, filesystem, ext4, hfs+

For many year, I had a media server that ran on Mac OS. I recently rebuilt it and I transferred some video files from a HFS+ drive to the Ext4 drive. Now that I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 I can't open any of my video files in VLC.

The weird thing is, that if I use a SAMBA share and open one of the video files on my Macbook Pro is plays fine. Something seems to be off with how the files transferred between the 2 filesystems.

I am looking for recommendations for how I can repair the files for the Ext4 filesystem to make them accessible on my Ubuntu machine.

I have check owner/group and permissions and all seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, all I had to do to fix the files on the Ext4 file system was to run a touch all command and they started work.

I am not sure why this worked, but I wanted to be sure to share my solution.

Comment: What is "touch all command"?

Comment: Browse to the correct directory and run `find  -type f  -exec touch {} +`